# PHP script doesnt redirect to "header" page

Tags: php, redirect, header

Here is the issue. I am trying to troubleshoot an issue in my PHP script that prevents it from emailing the info, our client has inputted.

```
<?php    
session_start();    
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
$recaptcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!empty($recaptcha))
{
include("getCurlData.php");
$google_url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$secret='6LegpgYTAAAAABK9Nd45_DfAPu7_gwHro9pj902B';
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url=$google_url."?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip;
$res=getCurlData($url);
$res= json_decode($res, true);
//reCaptcha success check
if($res['success'])
{

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $to = "denislav@svishtov.net";
  $subject = "New opinion post";

  // data the visitor provided
  $name_field = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $phone_field = filter_var($_POST['number']);
  $address_field = filter_var($_POST['address'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $comment = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  //constructing the message
  $body = "
  From: $name_field <br/>
  Email Address: $address_field <br/>
  Phone number: $phone_field <br/>
  Message:<br/> $comment ";

  // ...and away we go!
  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

  // redirect to confirmation
  header("Location: confirmation2.html");
  }

  else {
  // handle the error somehow
  echo "Error accessing the file";
  }

  }
  else
  {
  echo "Въвели сте грешен код за потвърждаване (reCAPTCHA)! Натиснете "назад" и опитайте отново";
  }

  }
  else
  {
  echo "Не сте въвели код за потвърждаване (reCAPTCHA)! Натиснете "назад" и опитайте отново";
  }
 }

  ?>
```

worse thing is , it used to work , then I opened it, edited some stuff and now it doesnt work, tried the back-up copy and it still doesnt work !? 
Working in CMS MadeSimple. the URLs are correct , the confirmation2.html is a file, not a page made in CMS and it is in the same folder as the php script and if I try to access it directly (not via the contact from) its there, I have tried ' ' and " " quotes, still no change.

Probably a simple mistake, I did try looking for other solutions in here (stackoverflow.com) but nothing to fix my current issue. I know that I shouldnt have any output before the header but... well I dont have any output so, I'm baffled.
Appreciation in advance to those who want to help!

Comment: You've forgotten an `exit();` after redirecting with `header("Location: confirmation2.html");`

Comment: Added , doesnt work :/   used to be ok without it before !?

Comment: Use `header("Location: /uploads/doc/Online_Request/confirmation2.html"); exit();` If it still doesn't work (whatever `doesn't work` might mean btw) then make sure the execution of your code steps in this case `if($res['success'])`

Comment: ' doesn't work ' means I get a blank page, as if I have tried to open the script directly and not thru the form. And yes it still ' doesn't work '
... also I don't have knowledge of how to troubleshoot and debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
Seems like the reCAPTCHA was shitting me, and after I removed it - WORKS.
Gonna leave it defenseless   for now. Thanks to all who wanted to help.